# Javascript operator && alternative option(required for limitation)

Tags: javascript

How I can write the following without `&&`?

```
if(a == 1 && b == 2) { ... }
```

Can I create a function for the operator?

Comment: You can put the `&&` into a function that returns a boolean, and pass your parameters in..but that's silly, unless you have to reuse it many times with the same format but different parameters.

Comment: Maybe it's an interview riddle

Comment: @Knownasilya You're still using `&&`, just adding more overhead.

Comment: `!(a != 1 || b != 2)` :)

Comment: Alexander's formula is based on [**De Morgan's law**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).

Comment: @madbreaks From the question, it seems like he doesn't want to use it in the `if` statement..but who knows.. kind of need more info.

Comment: I doubt it is what OP wanted. If by chance it is then I will put it as an answer. Anyways, more information is needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a function to encapsulate your operation:

```
function compare(a, b, value1, value2) {
    if(a === value1) {
        if(b === value2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And you can use it like so:

```
if(compare(a, b, 1, 2)) {
    // Your action..
}
```

Comment: This is not equivalent if `a` and `b` are arbitrary expressions!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that statement?

Comment: I have [**explained it in my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13779572/383124).

Comment: You never explaind why though, you said that you cannot do it one way, and provided an alternate way. The only reason you gave was cosmetic.. I think you need to clarify what you mean, and why it cannot be done with a function.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this like

```
if(a==1){
  if(b==2){
    JS function
  }
}
```

Both will work the same but `if(a==1 && b==2)` is a good approach to do exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you'd want to do this, but you could nest `if` statements:

```
if(a == 1){
    if(b == 2){
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you could use a bitwise operator, if you really just need to consider `2` and `1`

```
if(b >> a === 1){
    ...
}
```

There are a lot ways to do it, but it really depends on your data.

Answer (score 1):

You could take advantage of prototypal inheritance, and create a constructor with its prototype extended with methods.

```
function Comparer(a, b) {
    if (!(this instanceof Comparer))
        return new Comparer(a, b);

    this.assign(a, b);
    this.compare();
}

Comparer.prototype.result = false;
Comparer.prototype.compare = function() {
    this.result = this.a == this.b;
};
Comparer.prototype.assign = function(a, b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
};
Comparer.prototype.and = function(a, b) {
    this.assign(a, b);
    if (this.result !== false) 
        this.compare();
    return this;
};
Comparer.prototype.or = function(a, b) {
    this.assign(a, b);
    if (this.result !== true) 
        this.compare();
    return this;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;

if (Comparer(a, 1).and(b, 2).result) 
    console.log("pass");
else
    console.log("fail");
```

---

We could even extend it to get rid of the `if` statement.

```
Comparer.prototype.then = function(fn) {
    if (this.result === true)
        fn();
    return this;
};
Comparer.prototype.otherwise = function(fn) {
    if (this.result === false)
        fn();
    return this;
};
```

And use it like this:

```
var a = 1,
    b = 2;

Comparer(a, 1)
    .and(b, 2)
    .then(function() { console.log("pass"); })
    .otherwise(function() { console.log("fail"); });
```

---

Or shorten things up like this:

```
var log = Function.bind.bind(console.log, console);

var a = 1,
    b = 2;

Comparer(a, 1)
    .and(b, 2)
    .then(log("pass"))
    .otherwise(log("fail"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the operator `&&` as a *function*, it's going to get ugly, because you need to pass the conditions as closures, whenever you care about short-circuiting with side-effects.

**Example**:

```
if(condition && changeTheWorld()) { ... }

// Cannot be translated into a function call of this nature:
if(land(condition, changeTheWorld()) { ... }
```

Instead, you would need to create a closure:

```
if(land(condition, function() {return changeTheWorld()}) {...}
```

As you can see, it's really cumbersome and verbose while there's no advantage.

If you really need this as a funciton, here is an

### Implementation with short-circuiting

This function emulates the semantics of `&&` correctly, if you pass the conditions that must not get evaluated—in the case of short-circuiting—as functions instead as expressions.

In other words, the function goes through the arguments in order, if one is a function, it evaluates it first, otherwise it just takes its value, if falsy, it aborts by returning false, otherwise, it continues with the next parameter.

```
function land(){
    for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var operand = arguments[i];
        var value = (typeof operand === 'function') ? operand() : operand;
        if (!value) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Example**:

```
function evaluateTo(result) {
    return function() {
            console.log("Evaluating " + result);
        return result;
    };
}

if(land(true, evaluateTo(1))) {
    console.log("All truthy");
}
// Outputs:
// Evaluating 1
// All truthy

if(land(evaluateTo(1), evaluateTo(0), evaluateTo(true))) {
    console.log("All truthy");
}
// Outputs:
// Evaluating 1
// Evaluating 0
```

**Obligatory missile example**

```
function changeTheWorld() {
    console.log("Missiles away!");
    // Firing 3 missiles
    return nukeTheGlobe(3);
}

if(false && changeTheWorld() == 3) { ... }
// we survived, missiles not fired

if(naiveLand(maybe, changeTheWorld() == 3) { ... }
// Missiles away! no matter what value `maybe` has

if(land(false, function(){ return changeTheWorld() == 3; })) {...}
// we survived, missiles not fired
```

Comment: Why do we need to pass the conditions as closures?

Comment: Please provide an *implementation* of this, as it stands your answer isn't an answer at all.

Comment: @Knownasilya `changeTheWorld()` is symbolic for any expression, that changes some state when evaluated. If `condition` before the `&&` operator evaluates to false, that state is not going to be changed. Imagine `changeTheWorld()` deletes a comment and `condition` is used to confirm the action. Without closures, the comment is going to be deleted no matter whether the deletion was confirmed or not.

Comment: @Madbreaks My answer is about the perils of implementing the `&&` as a function naively and entirely symbolic because of that. Moreover, it is about how you would use the function if you did correctly replicate the semantics of `&&` and how it's going to turn out. An implementation of `land` is not necessary to understand my answer.

Comment: @Madbreaks In what way? I can give an implementation, but I'd like to know why I have to go through that effort since I can't see how it adds value to my explanation.

Comment: You make a lot of broad statements as if they're facts, however you provide nothing to support those statements. You then provide what you say is "the right way to do it", but you don't provide an implementation that actually shows it working within op's parameters (a = 1, b = 2).

Comment: @Madbreaks Hmm, I didn't realize that I was. If you can point out which those statements are, I'm happy to change them or add further explanations.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. how can `if(confirmDelete) { if(delete()) { console.log("deleted") } }` ever evaluate to "deleted" if `confirmDelete` is `false`? I don't see how it can get there with the `&&` or nested `if`s..

Comment: @Knownasilya The premise of my answer is this `Can I create a function for the operator?`, i.e. creating a function, that has the same semantics as the `&&` operator. In your example, you extract the entire composite condition from the OP's code and stuff it into a function. I understood that particular phrase as providing  a general function, that implements `&&`, and knows nothing about any specific use case. In that case, you cannot mention `confirmDelete` *inside* the function, because that would not yield in an implementation of the operator.

Comment: @Madbreaks Perhaps that is the misunderstanding. I was only talking about implementing `&&` as a function in general, which was my understanding of the above quoted statement by the OP. I didn't realize it might be interpreted differently, but my way is hinted at by my naming the function `land` for "logical and".

Comment: @Knownasilya I have added an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is sort of pointless, but you could use the multiplication operator `*` instead of `&&`:

```
if(a==1 * b==2){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This does not preserve short-circuiting.

Comment: @phant0m Yes, but the results are equivalent.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by results. If `b` is an expression that changes state, for instance a function call, then the result may be far from equal.

Comment: @phant0m Where is *that* requirement in op's question?

Comment: @Madbreaks He wants an alternative. If you're going to present an alternative that does not do the same thing in all cases, that's not good or should be explained.

Comment: @phant0m In what circumstance could evaluating the expression `b` trigger a change of state? Go ahead, I'll wait.

Comment: Assuming `b` is symbolic for any expression, it might very well be a function call.

Comment: @phant0m `b` being "symbolic" for anything is not remotely implied by the question, this is an extrapolation on your part.

Comment: The OP asks about creating a function for the operator, since the operator `&&` works for any two expressions, it's only reasonable to provide an alternative that works for any two expressions. Further, the variable names being `a` and `b` imply that it's a contrived and simplified example, where the real question is about `&&`, not `a` and `b`, which are thus symbolic placeholders.